# Color change of area under a curve

Tags: plotting, color

I am trying to set a graph to show the value of the equity of an investment based on whether the portfolio is invested or in cash. I tried using the `ColorFunction`, but was not successful. Here is the sample data.

```
colorCash = RGBColor[90/255, 180/255, 172/255];
colorInvested = RGBColor[216/255, 179/255, 101/255];
invested = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};

period = {
   {2005, 7, 1}, {2005, 8, 1}, {2005, 9, 1}, {2005, 10, 3}, {2005, 11, 1}, {2005, 12, 1},
   {2006, 1, 3}, {2006, 2, 1}, {2006, 3, 1}, {2006, 4, 3}, {2006, 5, 1}, {2006, 6, 1},
   {2006, 7, 3}, {2006, 8, 1}, {2006, 9, 1}, {2006, 10, 2}, {2006, 11, 1}, {2006, 12, 1},
   {2007, 1, 3}, {2007, 2, 1}, {2007, 3, 1}, {2007, 4, 2}, {2007, 5, 1}, {2007, 6, 1},
   {2007, 7, 2}, {2007, 8, 1}, {2007, 9, 4}, {2007, 10, 1}, {2007, 11, 1}, {2007, 12, 3},
   {2008, 1, 2}, {2008, 2, 1}, {2008, 3, 3}, {2008, 4, 1}, {2008, 5, 1}, {2008, 6, 2},
   {2008, 7, 1}, {2008, 8, 1}, {2008, 9, 2}, {2008, 10, 1}, {2008, 11, 3}, {2008, 12, 1},
   {2009, 1, 2}, {2009, 2, 2}, {2009, 3, 2}, {2009, 4, 1}, {2009, 5, 1}, {2009, 6, 1},
   {2009, 7, 1}, {2009, 8, 3}, {2009, 9, 1}, {2009, 10, 1}, {2009, 11, 2}, {2009, 12, 1},
   {2010, 1, 4}, {2010, 2, 1}, {2010, 3, 1}, {2010, 4, 1}, {2010, 5, 3}, {2010, 6, 1},
   {2010, 7, 1}, {2010, 8, 2}, {2010, 9, 1}, {2010, 10, 1}, {2010, 11, 1}, {2010, 12, 1},
   {2011, 1, 3}, {2011, 2, 1}, {2011, 3, 1}, {2011, 4, 1}, {2011, 5, 2}, {2011, 6, 1},
   {2011, 7, 1}, {2011, 8, 1}, {2011, 9, 1}, {2011, 10, 3}, {2011, 11, 1}, {2011, 12, 1},
   {2012, 1, 3}, {2012, 2, 1}, {2012, 3, 1}, {2012, 4, 2}, {2012, 5, 1}, {2012, 6, 1}};

equity = {100, 100, 100, 107.60368663594471, 106.91244239631337, 113.13364055299542,
          118.84792626728114, 130.6451612903226, 129.19354838709677, 133.8709677419355,
          149.97695852534562, 147.99539170506912, 141.08294930875573, 145.52995391705065,
   143.52534562211977, 137.02764976958522, 137.02764976958522, 137.02764976958522,
   134.51650476681908, 137.964008923159, 141.4753557490608, 139.9005698998685,
   142.77349003015175, 139.47495210278947, 136.77227909133777, 136.77227909133777,
   138.2898921592307, 152.82155701480832, 163.44484849005894, 160.74224987600297,
   171.42790901157795, 190.01347178823949, 199.95071899992203, 187.95533899753534,
   180.13859223688132, 181.8017298455311, 190.01347178823949, 187.2692947339673,
   187.2692947339673, 187.2692947339673, 187.2692947339673, 187.2692947339673,
   187.2692947339673, 197.63707006655756, 200.49416055487052, 195.407673700677,
   188.89264160232702, 208.22129164826242, 197.3556899427086, 202.0525735484958,
   202.16079667305314, 213.9571172497998, 221.92233921721777, 250.29844247614417,
   232.26846992489646, 229.34644556184912, 236.85713040612634, 235.8181884103762,
   249.69239297862313, 257.3113009474577, 263.37179592266705, 249.97377310247217,
   264.2375809191255, 276.85639724250774, 287.0510155758062, 293.1115105510154,
   300.2542367717978, 281.0987437251542, 297.95990653118287, 302.7217240117045,
   329.79914977594314, 323.8901671751141, 316.011523707342, 342.6127677235285,
   384.66827392649884, 342.11494135056495, 362.2011532684015, 368.24000361869935,
   328.9766540293077, 328.9766540293077, 319.22257687363395, 319.22257687363395,
   319.22257687363395, 319.22257687363395};
```

The following charts show the value of the portfolio and whether I am an investor or not:

```
Column[{
        DateListPlot[Transpose[{period, equity}], Filling -> Axis, 
          Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large], 
        DateListPlot[Transpose[{period, invested}], Filling -> Axis, 
          ImageSize -> Large]
}]
```

This is what I tried to change the color, but it is not the correct thing to do as the period painted does not coincide with the investment period:

```
myColor = If[# == 1, colorInvested, colorCash] & /@ invested;

DateListPlot[Transpose[{period, equity}], Filling -> Axis, 
 Joined -> True, ColorFunction -> myColor, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ColorFunction` is usually supposed to be a function rather than a list of colours.  Unfortunately for a `DateListPlot` it only seems to give you the y-coordinate as input and not the x-coordinate (i.e. the date).  If you give it a list instead of a function, it will colour based on height, e.g.:

```
DateListPlot[Transpose[{period, equity}], Joined -> True, Filling -> Axis,
   ColorFunction -> {Red, Blue, Green, Yellow}]
```

[image]

You could manually construct some polygons to do the filling you require:

```
prolog = Partition[Thread[{invested, period, equity}], 2, 1] /.
   {{i_, d1_, e1_}, {_, d2_, e2_}} -> {If[i == 0, colorCash, colorInvested],
      Polygon[{{d1, 0}, {d2, 0}, {d2, e2}, {d1, e1}}]};

DateListPlot[Transpose[{period, equity}], Joined -> True, Prolog -> prolog]
```

[image]

But you do get ugly seams between polygons.

**EDIT**

Fix for polygon seams as suggested by @kguler:

```
prolog = Partition[Thread[{invested, period, equity}], 2, 1] /.
   {{i_, d1_, e1_}, {_, d2_, e2_}} -> With[{c = If[i == 0, colorCash, colorInvested]},
   {c, EdgeForm[c], Polygon[{{d1, 0}, {d2, 0}, {d2, e2}, {d1, e1}}]}];

DateListPlot[Transpose[{period, equity}], Joined -> True, Prolog -> prolog]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you specify a function to `ColorFunction`, i.e. `ColorFunction -> fun`, the arguments supplied to `fun` will be the `x` and `y` coordinates, so you could specify a colour function according to

```
myColor = Blend[{colorCash, colorInvested}, 
   Interpolation[Transpose[{Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[invested] - 1)], invested}]][#]] &
```

Then

```
DateListPlot[Transpose[{period, equity}], Filling -> Axis, 
 Joined -> True, ColorFunction -> myColor, ImageSize -> Large, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which gives the right colours for the right intervals but the transitions are a bit fuzzy.

Comment: Riddle me this, Batman: What's the difference between `ColorFunction -> (wat[x__] := (Print[x]; Red); wat)` and `ColorFunction -> ((Print[##]; Red) &)`?

Comment: @wxffles Interesting. It seems that pure functions are treated differently from named functions. I vaguely remember that for some options you have to use pure functions and that Mathematica will complain if you use named ones, but I can't remember which ones.

Comment: @Heike probably only in the un-birthday options

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach to using `Prolog` or `ColorFunction` is to plot the original series together with a copy in which equity value is replaced with `MissingValue` for in-cash periods. Using

```
eqdt = Transpose[{period, equity}];
opts = {Filling -> Axis,  FillingStyle -> {1 -> colorCash, 2 -> colorInvested}, 
  Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large};
```

the simple approach

```
eqdtInv = eqdt;
eqdtInv[[Flatten@Position[invested, 0], 2]] = Missing["NotAvaiable"];
DateListPlot[{eqdt, eqdtInv}, opts]
```

produces plots in which single investment periods that fall between in-cash periods are not visible. One way to fix this issue is to insert data points in appropriate places, as in

```
eqdtInv2 = #[[2 ;;]] & /@ (Transpose[{invested, period, equity}] 
    /. {a___, {0, d1_, e1_}, {1, d2_, e2_}, {0, d3_, e3_}, b___} :> 
    {a, {0, d1, e1}, {1, d2, e2}, {1,DatePlus[d3, {-1, "Hour"}], e3}, {0, d3, e3}, b} 
    /. {0, d1_, e1_} :> {0, d1, Missing["NotAvailable"]})
```

Now, to compare the two approaches

```
Row[{DateListPlot[{eqdt, eqdtInv}, opts], Spacer[15],DateListPlot[{eqdt, eqdtInv2}, opts]}]
```

we get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd have done something similar to Heike's answer, with the difference of exploiting the fact that `DateListPlot[]` uses absolute times (i.e. the output of `AbsoluteTime[]` after being applied to a date list like `{2005, 7, 1}`) as the abscissa (note that this is in fact mentioned in the docs for `DateListPlot[]`):

```
investedFunction = Interpolation[Transpose[{AbsoluteTime /@ period, invested}],
                                 InterpolationOrder -> 1];

DateListPlot[Transpose[{period, equity}], 
             ColorFunction -> (Blend[{colorCash, colorInvested}, investedFunction[#1]] &),
             ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Filling -> Axis, Joined -> True]
```

[image: colored date list plot]

Note that there is no assumption here that the dates are equispaced.