# DateListPlot FillingStyle problem

Tags: graphics

In the following query, If the option `PlotStyle->{Red,Blue}` is inserted it works but `FillingStyle->{Red,Blue}` does not: The filling turns all Blue. Is this a known issue? I tried basic `ColorFunction`  but could only get rainbows. Any other options? It's desirable to alternate the segments using only 2 colors (though not Red and Blue, that's just for example).

```
Labeled[DateListPlot[#, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 1000, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/5, 
    Epilog -> {Inset[
       Text[Style[">statigrafix<", Blue, Opacity[0.1], 
         FontFamily -> "Consolas", FontSize -> 14]], 
       Scaled[{0.15, 0.75}]]}, Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
    Filling -> Bottom, GridLines -> None] &@
  Split[FinancialData["^DJI", "Close", "Jan 1 1980"], 
   Not@(#[[2]] > 10000 && #2[[2]] <= 10000) &],
 Style["Dow Jones Industial 1.1.80-6.22.12 segmented by 10k \
crossings", Gray, Opacity[0.3], FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], Bottom]
```

Comment: Can you attach a pic of what you are seeing?

Comment: Sure, what's the procedure for uploading a .png?

Comment: Tried setting the options as `Filling -> Axis,  FillingStyle -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Blue}, , ColorFunctionScaling->False`?

Comment: @kguler, just tried it: as is, it only colors the first two segments in Red and Blue, while the remaining filling regions retain their default colors. I suppose a Table using Mod[k,2] to maps odd and even numbers to Red, Blue would work but it's awful to have to compute and pass the number of segments.

Comment: sorry... this should work: `PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, FillingStyle ->  Table[i -> If[OddQ[i], Red, Blue], {i, 
   200}], ColorFunctionScaling -> False` 200 should be replace with the length of the list produced by `Split`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping `InputForm` around your code will explain why the plot line is blue and not red.

`FillingStyle` is rather limited.

```
FillingStyle->{Red,Blue}
```

means that everything above your line to the filling point will be red and everything below the line to the filling point will be blue. Since your filling point is `Bottom` you should only see blue filling.

e.g.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> {Red,Blue}]
```

and

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {Red,Blue}]
```

Comment: Mike, thx for explaining. Fyi InputForm for the my code is way too long to parse manually, consisting of thousands of graphical elements... Also, I accepted your answer but would  still like to know a run-around using ColorFunction if possible. You owe me... just kiddin.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge this is not a `ColorFunction` issue, nor is that the place to look for a solution. @kguler has pointed in the right direction with specific rules but I would do it a bit differently -- depending on what you want the product to look like. While what you got is what I'd expect you to get it is unclear to me what you want the final plot to look like. Can you please explain/expand.

Answer (score 3):

Using randomdata (do not have access to FinancialData at the time): with

```
randomdata = Thread[{DateList[{1980, 1, #}] & /@ Range[500],  RandomReal[{5000, 15000}, {500}]}];
inpdta = Split[randomdata,Not@(#[[2]] > 10000 && #2[[2]] <= 10000) &];
```

and

```
 Labeled[DateListPlot[#, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 1000, AspectRatio -> 1/5, 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
 Filling -> Bottom, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 FillingStyle -> Table[i -> If[OddQ[i], Red, Blue], {i, Length@inpdta}], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,  
 GridLines -> None] &@  inpdta,
   Style["Dow Jones Industial 1.1.80-6.22.12 segmented by 10k crossings", Gray, Opacity[0.8], FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], Bottom]
```

you get

[image]

**EDIT:** Splitting the data produces white lines between sub-series. For several alternatives to get rid of these artifacts pls see  [this question and answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6461/125).

**EDIT 2:** Without having to pre-split the data and using `ColorFunction` (with a portion of the data)

```
 DateListPlot[randomdata[[1 ;; 100]], Joined -> True, Filling -> Bottom, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Switch[Boole[y < 10000], 1, Red, 0, Blue]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

**EDIT 3:** The following is perhaps the simplest way to get the same plot. The key step is to take every other part of list of sub-series produced by `Split` and overlay it (using `Show`) on top of a plain listplot of the source data. The added advantage is that you don't get coloring artifacts around the boundaries of regions.

```
 Show[DateListPlot[randomdata, Joined -> True, Filling -> Bottom, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, FillingStyle -> Red], 
  DateListPlot[Split[randomdata, Not@(#[[2]] > 10000 && #2[[2]] <= 10000) &][[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]], 
  Joined -> True, Filling -> Bottom, PlotStyle -> Blue, FillingStyle -> Blue]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solutions, particularly edits #2 and #3 - thanks kguler