# How to change the filling color under a plot according to a value?

Tags: plotting

Mathematica has an option to fill the space under a curve with a value:

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[data][[1]], Filling -> Axis]
```

I have a dataset data=$\{\{val_1,class_1\},\{val_2,class_2\},\{val_3,class_3\}\ldots\}$. The values $val_i$ are what is to be plotted while the values $class_i$ are which class the value belongs to.

I would like to be able to change the color of the filling under the curves of values $val_1,val_2,val_3,\ldots$ according to which class $class_1,class_2,class_3,\ldots$ the value belongs to.

For example, $class_1$ would be `Blue`, $class_2$ would be `Red` and $class_3$ would be `Green`...

A numerical example: I have the dataset:

```
{{0.9,"A"},{1.9,"A"},{1.2,"C"},{1.0,"B"},{2.5,"D"},...}
```

I want to plot `{0.9,1.9,1.2,1.0,2.5}` according to their `A,B,C,D` labels...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you mean something like this?

```
SeedRandom[1];
classes = {1, 2, 3};
data = Transpose[{Range[100]^2, RandomChoice[classes, 100]}];

ListPlot[classes /. 
  GroupBy[MapIndexed[First /@ {#2, #1} &, data], data[[First@#, 2]] &],
 Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Alternate solution**

```
dataIF = Interpolation[data[[All, 1]], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
cf[class_] := class /. {1 -> Blue, 2 -> Red, 3 -> Green};

ParametricPlot[{x, t dataIF[x]}, {x, 1, 100}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 Mesh -> {Range[0, 100] + 1/2}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> None,
 MeshShading -> cf /@ data[[All, 2]], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Well, it uses the OP's color suggestions. :)

Comment: I understood something similar, but the OP wants `ListLinePlot[]`, which is problematic because the color of the first (or last) trapezoid is undefined

Comment: @belisarius Yes, `ListLinePlot` may be impossible to use.  But before going into it further, I think the question needs clarification about which of the proposed answers, if any, are on target.

Comment: @belisarius Of course, you just gave me another idea...

Comment: Since the OP doesn't react I dare to upvote your answer.

Comment: Well, I can't upvote twice :)

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Using `ColorFunction` introduces blending of colors in region boundaries (see the original post below). Two approaches to get clear separation of colors appeared [in this related Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6461/125) (1) [split the data and overlay separate plots using Show](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6485/125), or (2) [construct polygons directly from the data and use them as Prolog](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6462/125). I use the latter method below.

```
SeedRandom[1];
classes = {1, 2, 3};
data2 = Transpose[{Range[100], Range[100]^2, RandomChoice[classes, 100]}];
```

Michael's color function

```
cf[class_] := class /. {1 -> Blue, 2 -> Red, 3 -> Green};
```

and a function to create polygons

```
epilogF = Partition[#, 2, 
    1] /. {{t1_, v1_, class_}, {t2_, v2_, _}} :> {c = cf[class], 
     EdgeForm[c], Polygon[{{t1, 0}, {t2, 0}, {t2, v2}, {t1, v1}}]}&;

Graphics[epilogF[data2], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> True]
(* or ListLinePlot[data2[[All,;;2]], Epilog -> epilogF[data2]] *)
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

Using Michael's example data with three classes

```
SeedRandom[1];
classes = {1, 2, 3};
data = Transpose[{Range[100]^2, RandomChoice[classes, 100]}];

intF = Interpolation[Last /@ data, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[data][[1]], Filling -> Axis,
   ColorFunction -> ({Blue, Red, Green}[[intF[#1]]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use a slightly modified version of Michael's `cf`:

```
cf2[x_] :=  data[[x, 2]] /. {1 -> Blue, 2 -> Red, 3 -> Green}; 
ListLinePlot[Transpose[data][[1]], Filling -> Axis, ColorFunction -> (cf2[#1] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
val1 = Array[Sin, 100, {0, 2 Pi}];
class1 = "a";
val2 = Array[Cos, 100, {0, 2 Pi}];
class2 = "b";

data = {{val1, class1}, {val2, class2}};
fillingstyle = Table[i -> {Axis, data[[i, 2]]}, {i, Length@data}]/.{"a" -> Gray, "b" -> Pink};

ListLinePlot[Transpose[data][[1]], Filling -> fillingstyle]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]