# How to apply color function to my financial indicator?

Tags: color, curated-data, finance, filling

My goal is to make a figure like this picture in a financial indicator,
[image]

I want to plot “a colored” financial indicator below a trading chart.

I prepared financial data and data of my indicator:

```
spy = FinancialData["SPY", "OHLCV", {{2020, 12, 1}, {2020, 12, 10}}];
indicatorData = {{{2020,12,1},1}, {{2020,12,2},2}, {{2020,12,3},3}, 
{{2020,12,4},-1}, {{2020,12,7},-2}, {{2020,12,8},-3}, {{2020,12,9},1}, 
{{2020, 12, 10}, 3}};
myIndicator = 
FinancialIndicator[TimeSeries[indicatorData] &, "LineStyle" -> Blue,
"IndexLine" -> 0];
```

The plot of the data is

```
TradingChart[spy, {myIndicator}]
```

[image]

I want to use `Hue` and `Filling` to fill the indicator with color, depending on "colorData" which is a set of dates and `Hue` values,

```
colorData = {{{2020,12,1}, Hue@0.2}, {{2020,12,2}, Hue@0.3}, 
{{2020,12,3}, Hue@0}, {{2020,12,4}, Hue@0.2}, {{2020,12,7}, Hue@0.5}, 
{{2020,12,8}, Hue@0.4}, {{2020,12, 9},Hue@0}, {{2020,12,10}, Hue@0}};
```

I need to fill the region between my indicator and x-axis by using `Filling`.

Although I guess `Hue` and `Filling` are keys to my question, any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to give up interactive display of legends, you can post-process `Setting @ TradingChart[...]` to get a graphics object with desired filling style:

```
myIndicator = FinancialIndicator[TimeSeries[indicatorData] &,
  "LineStyle" -> Blue, "IndexLine" -> 0]; 

Setting @ TradingChart[spy, {myIndicator}, ImageSize -> Large] /.  
 subplot : Line[MapIndexed[N@{#2[[1]], #} &, indicatorData[[All, -1]]]] :> 
  {First @ 
   ListLinePlot[First @ subplot, Filling -> 0, 
          FillingStyle -> Automatic, 
          ColorFunction -> (Blend[colorData[[All, 2]], #] &)], 
   subplot}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your idea, that never crossed my mind. But, this time I don't want to give up interactive display.  [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6461/color-change-of-area-under-a-curve/6492#6492) is also useful If I don't use `Tradingchart`...