# Coloring my Financial Indicator

Tags: color, charts, curated-data

I want to plot a trading chart with my indicator that is colored depending on its height.

I prepared financial data and data of my indicator:

```
spy = FinancialData["SPY", "OHLCV", {{2020, 12, 1}, {2020, 12, 10}}];
indicatorData = {{{2020,12,1},1}, {{2020,12,2},2}, {{2020,12,3},3}, 
{{2020,12,4},-1}, {{2020,12,7},-2}, {{2020,12,8},-3}, {{2020,12,9},1}, {{2020, 12, 10}, 3}};
myIndicator = 
FinancialIndicator[TimeSeries[indicatorData] &, "IndexLine" -> 0, "LineStyle" -> Blue, Filling -> 0];
```

The plot is given by

```
TradingChart[spy, {myIndicator}]
```

with "the uniform Blue color" indicator.
It is natural consequence because in `myIndicator` I chose "LineStyle" to be `Blue`.

[image]

Now, I want to change the blue curve to new one that changes its color depending on its value (height).
For example, the curve is red when its value is higher than 1, while it is blue when it is lower than 0.

Is it possible to do this?

I tried a simple attempt by changing `"LineStyle" -> Blue` to `"LineStyle" -> "Rainbow"`, but, this did not work.

This question may be related to [my previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262643/how-to-apply-color-function-to-my-financial-indicator).

Any comment is welcome.

Comment: does this give what you need: `myIndicator =  FinancialIndicator[TimeSeries[indicatorData] &, "IndexLine" -> 0, 
   "LineStyle" -> Opacity[0], Filling -> {1 -> {0, {Red, Blue}}}]; TradingChart[spy, {myIndicator}]`?

Comment: @kglr Thanks, your suggestion worked, but, actually I need more. For instance, I want my indicator to be exactly like this: Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[y]],  Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Automatic]. This plot gives a curve filled with rainbow color that depends on its height.